# Newline positions

Tags: ruby, string

Given a string, what is the most efficient way to return an array of the character position of the beginning of newlines in the string?

```
text =<<_
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in 
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
_
```

Expected:

```
find_newlines(text) # => [0, 80, 155, 233, 313, 393]
```

I post my own answers. I would like to accept the fastest way as the accepted answer.

---

**Benchmark result here will be updated when a new answer is added**

```
require "fruity"

compare do
  padde1 {find_newlines_padde1(text)}
  digitalross1 {find_newlines_digitalross1(text)}
  sawa1 {find_newlines1(text)}
  sawa2 {find_newlines2(text)}
end

# Running each test 512 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# digitalross1 is faster than sawa2 by 5x ± 0.1
# sawa2 is faster than sawa1 by 21.999999999999996% ± 1.0%
# sawa1 is faster than padde1 by 4.0000000000000036% ± 1.0%
```

Comment: Your expected output seems incorrect. The first value will *always* be 0, and so measures nothing. Worse, the last value, the **393,** is not actually the last newline. It's the newline after *sunt in* and not the newline position after *est laborum*.

Comment: But +1 anyway. I love the contest format.

Comment: Same here, feels a bit like code golf but for speed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def find_newlines text
  s = 0
  [0] + text.to_a[0..-2].map { |e| s += e.size }
end
```

As noted, use `text.each_line.to_a` for 1.9. Calling `each_line` also works in 1.8.7, but it's 20% slower than calling only `to_a.`

Comment: This won’t work on Ruby 1.9+ (`String` no longer includes `Enumerable`), but `text.each_line.to_a ...` does.

Comment: This is the fastest besides padde's one using C.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to your answer:

```
def find_newlines_padde1 text
  text.enum_for(:scan, /^/).map do
    $~.begin(0)
  end
end
```

You can still gain some performance with [rubyinline](https://github.com/seattlerb/rubyinline):

```
require "inline"
module Kernel
  inline :C do |builder|
    builder.add_compile_flags '-std=c99'
    builder.c %q{
      static VALUE find_newlines_padde2(VALUE str) {
        char newline = '\n';
        char* s = RSTRING_PTR(str);
        VALUE res = rb_ary_new();
        str = StringValue(str);
        rb_ary_push(res, LONG2FIX(0));
        for (long pos=0; pos<RSTRING_LEN(str)-1; pos++) {
          if (s[pos] == newline) {
             rb_ary_push(res, LONG2FIX(pos+1));
          }
        }
        return res;
      }
    }
  end
end
```

Note that i'm artificially ending early with `pos<RSTRING_LEN(str)-1` to get the same result you requested. You can change this to `pos<RSTRING_LEN(str)` if you like, so the last empty line counts as a line start, too. You will have decide which one works for you.

Fruity says `padde2 is faster than sawa2 by 22x ± 0.1`

Comment: Check out my update, i can't make it faster unless maybe i start writing inline assembler in the inline c code ;-)

Comment: Since `res[0]` will always be 0, perhaps it should be removed or be optional.

Comment: I just tailored this method to return the same value as @sawa's approaches. It simply depends on how he wants to use this. However, i don't think adding the zero is critical to performance here because it's outside of the loop and thus only adds a constant to the execution time.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't run `inline` correctly. It seems to using a colon for delimiters between the the `when` condition and the rest, and that returns a syntax error.

Comment: Which version of ruby, rubyinline and which platform are you using?

Comment: You could still use a plain old ruby extension, there are plenty of tutorials out there.

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_newlines_sawa1 s
  a = []
  s.scan(/^/){a.push($~.offset(0)[0])}
  a
end

find_newlines_sawa1(text) # => [0, 80, 155, 233, 313, 393]

def find_newlines_sawa2 s
  a = [0]
  s.split(/^/).each{|s| a.push(a.last + s.length)}
  a.pop
  a
end

find_newlines_sawa2(text) # => [0, 80, 155, 233, 313, 393]
```

Comment: I was going to do it when some more answers are around. It does not make sense for each answer to have its own benchmark run on a different computer.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Can you give it a try?

Comment: I would, but it's too late now. Maybe tomorrow.

Comment: Note that sawa2 returns `[]` for an empty string whereas sawa1, padde1 and padde2 return `[0]` and DigitalRoss' method raises an exception.